# Why am I getting a TypeError in my function?

Tags: python, typeerror

I wrote this function to "score" hands for a Python blackjack game (I know aces can be 1 or 11, that's a future problem to figure out). The input is a list of tuples (cards), and the rank can be either 2-10 or A, J, K, or Q.

I'm sometimes getting a TypeError that reads `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` in reference to `score = score + rank`. I'm not sure why there's an issue though, because if it gets to that point the rank must be an int. Anyone see the issue?

```
def analyzeHand(hand):
    score = 0
    for card in hand:
        rank = card[0]
        if (rank == 'A'):
            score = score + 11
        if (rank == 'K' or rank == 'Q' or rank == 'J'):
            score = score + 10
        else:
            score = score + rank
    return score
```

Comment: You should debug your code. Print `rank` before adding it to score. It may not be an integer.

Comment: Your second `if` should be `elif`. Otherwise, if `rank` is `'A'`, the `else` block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That `score = score + rank` in the last else should likely be

```
score += int(rank)
```

because from context `rank` is of type `str`, assumed to be "2".."9".

Comment: Nit: It *is* a string per the error, the assumption is then only on the value(s).